# install by bash

Tags: server, bash, mysql

I install mysql-server by bash. But i can't make it auto enter password for root (this image below).

[image]

And here's my code.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/userver2
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
113phantom 
113phantom
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: it is:
`113phantom
113phantom`
in my code. it's not auto pass the enter password for root step

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install MySQL without a password prompt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79257/how-do-i-install-mysql-without-a-password-prompt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big thread here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739645/install-mysql-on-ubuntu-without-password-prompt

This way, you declare the password before you install the package.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/userver2
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 113phantom'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 113phantom'
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Comment: oh, thank you so much. Is that suitable for any package?

Comment: Yes, but you obviously have to know the key to use in `debconf-set-selections` (like here `mysql-server/root_password_again` for the second password prompt).  You can inspect any Debconf template in the package file, or just install it manually once and see which settings it installed with `dpkg-get-selections`.

Comment: The `cd` is completely redundant here; these commands do not touch any files in the current working directory.