# How to create ubuntu iso with extra selected packages?

Tags: 14.04, iso

I want to create a new ubuntu iso, with extra packages like mysql, pip, etc

I want to install ubuntu on all computers of our computer lab(around 300 computers). for various courses, a set of packages need to be installed. The lab has very slow Internet connection. So i'm looking for a way to create a new ubuntu iso with extra packages?

Comment: how to setup root user and password for mysql. i.e how to skip configuration for some packages.

Comment: Use the search: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79257/how-do-i-install-mysql-without-a-password-prompt