# How to complete `mariadb-server`'s installation without being stopped at "Enter the password"?

Tags: 14.04, mariadb

Is there any way to install `mariadb-server` and auto-set the password for the database?
For example: `sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server` is to avoid 'Y/N' during the package installation.

Now, I want to avoid entering the password for the database.

Comment: If you run commands as root you won't have to give any passwords. `sudo su` will log you in as root.

Comment: @EduardoCola I suspect the question is  referring to the post-install configuration step that asks for a *database* root password - rather than to a password being required to run the install command

Comment: @steeldriver if that's the case, then it's probably a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/79257/how-do-i-install-mysql-without-a-password-prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, thanks for your help, but below lines worked for me.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mariadb-server mysql-server/root_password password $PASSWORD"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mariadb-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $PASSWORD" 

sudo apt-get install -y mariadb-server python-mysqldb
```

Comment: This might be easier in some contexts:
`echo "mariadb-server mysql-server/root_password password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" | sudo debconf-set-selections`

Answer (score 0):

switch to root first:

```
sudo su
```

you will have to input the password after that once in order to become root.
But after that you can use any command without having to input the password again (e.g. for an apt-get installation), as long as you stay in that terminal.

Comment: Basically, I am writing a script and I have included this line in it, 'sudo apt-get install mariadb-server'                                                            And I want to run the script and auto-install the application without asking for any input, but when I run the script it asks me to set mariadb user password. Can I by pass this thing to make a smooth installation??

Answer (score 0):

I use these scripts for installing/reinstalling Mariadb-Server 10.3.

Be sure to execute the scripts with...

`"sudo bash mariadb.10.3.install.sh"`
...because the script does need super user permission.

```
mariadb.10.3.install.sh

apt update
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password password choose_a-password'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password_again password choose_a_password'
apt install mariadb-server-10.3 -y
echo 'Finnished reinstalling MariaDB Server 10.3'
```

And here comes my reinstallation script for reinstalling and erase every trace of my previous installed copy of `MariaDB-Server-10.3`.

Be sure to execute the scripts with...

`"sudo bash mariadb.10.3.reinstall.completely.sh"`

...because the script does need super user permission.

Mariadb.10.3.reinstall.completely.sh

```
echo 'Running reinstall script for any and all versions ofMariaDB Server'
echo 'Uninstalling MariaDB Server Software'
apt --remove purge mariadb-server* -y
echo 'Removing left over files from any MariaDB Server Installation....'
apt -y autoremove 
apt autoclean
apt clean all 
rm -rf /etc/mysql/ /var/lib/mysql/ /var/log/mysql
apt clean 
echo 'Installing MariaDB Server 10.3 from scratch...'
apt update
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password password choose_a_password'
debconf-set-selections <<< 'mariadb-server-10.3 mysql-server/root_password_again password choose_a_password'
apt install mariadb-server-10.3 -y
echo 'Finnished reinstalling MariaDB Server 10.3'
```

I hope this helps.